# Flutter Maven error while trying to download jars from Android studio for Azure Notification Hub

Tags: android, maven, flutter, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to build a flutter app for Azure Notifications hub using the sample code under git and my buildgradle file is as below

build.gradle

```
group 'com.swiftoffice.azure_notificationhubs_flutter'
version '1.0'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK"
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
        implementation 'com.microsoft.azure:notification-hubs-android-sdk:0.6@aar'
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK"
    }
}
```

While trying to build I am getting TIME OUT error, but when I tried to download the jars directly from the above URL using browser, it worked.

I have no proxy enabled under settings. Please tell me where under the project structure I can place the jars manually, so the build process continues

Error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.microsoft.azure:notification-hubs-android-sdk:0.6.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :azure_notificationhubs_flutter
      > Could not resolve com.microsoft.azure:notification-hubs-android-sdk:0.6.
         > Could not get resource 'http://download.flutter.io/com/microsoft/azure/notification-hubs-android-sdk/0.6/notification-hubs-android-sdk-0.6.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'http://download.flutter.io/com/microsoft/azure/notification-hubs-android-sdk/0.6/notification-hubs-android-sdk-0.6.pom'.
               > Read timed out

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 37s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: I haven't spent any time with Flutter, so I'm unfortunately a little out of my depth in understanding what's going wrong here. Reading through your configuration and the error, it seems you are trying to get the SDK from bintray, which is correct. But then it looks like from the error output that it's trying to download the SDK from download.flutter.io instead. That seems like the issue. The fact it's timing out is likely because there aren't any published packages for Azure Notification Hubs on flutter.io.